# Ggplot2: geom or aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand the logic of the ggplot syntax and I don't understand why sometimes some parameters are in the geom part instead of the aes part.

For instance in `geom_text` in which case `size` have to be specified in `geom` instead of `aes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ggplot `aes()` is used to map a variable to the way it is displayed. Extending the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html), if one wants to vary the `geom_text()` by `cyl` one would do

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text(aes(size = cyl))
```

[image: aes]

Alternatively, one might wish to set an arbitrary value for all of the text displayed:

```
p + geom_text(size = 10)
```

[image: arbitrary]